# Why don't my query params exist when using useRouter? nextjs

Tags: next.js

I have a nextjs route that is being hit.  Here is the url

`localhost:8080/eft-files/133722?enableRegen=true`.

In my `/pages` folder, here is the code I am using to get the query params.

```
const EftFileViewWrapper = () => {
  const {
    query: { eftFileId, enableRegen }
  } = useRouter();

  return (
    <EftFileView
      eftFileId={eftFileId}
      enableRegen={enableRegen}
    />
  );
};
```

When the app routes via a `next/link`,  initially the `enableRegen` is `true`, but this file gets hit a second time and `enableRegen` is then `undefined`.  `eftFileId` is always populated.

If I do a hard refresh on the page, and don't route to it via a `next/link`, I always get the right values for all query params.

I have had to use `URLSearchParams` to make this work, like this:

```
const EftFileViewWrapper = () => {
  const {
    query: { eftFileId, enableRegen }
  } = useRouter();

  let params = isInBrowser && new URLSearchParams(location.search);

  return (
    <EftFileView
      eftFileId={eftFileId}
      enableRegen={enableRegen || params.get("enableRegen")}
    />
  );
};
```

I would rather stay in the nextjs ecosystem, but am not sure what to do.  Any ideas?

Comment: can you show how you declare `<Link>` ? are you passing the query to the query prop or just the string? usually you take the query vars inside `Page.getInitialProps`

Answer (score -2):

`useRouter` works only with paths and doesn't parse query params.

I suggest you use `window.location` in order to obtain the search params and then parse it with `URLSearchParams`. Of course, check that the `window` object is presented:

```js
let enableGen = false

if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
  enableGen = params.get("enableRegen")
}
```